# Rebuilding ConsumerWidget on changes to nested provider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm using Riverpod in my Flutter application, and I've run into an issue where my `ConsumerWidget` isn't rebuilding when changes occur in a nested provider.

I have a `BankrollListScreen` which watches the `bankrollListControllerProvider`. Inside the build method, I loop through a list of `Bankroll` objects and for each `Bankroll`, I want to display its total which I calculate using the `bankrollTotalProvider`.

```dart
// this is simplified version of my code
class BankrollListScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const BankrollListScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    AsyncValue<List<Bankroll>> bankrollListValue =
        ref.watch(bankrollListControllerProvider);

    return bankrollListValue.when(
      data: (bankrollList) => ListView(
        children: [
          for (var bankroll in bankrollList)
            GameSessionListTile(
              bankrollTotal: Text(
                ref.watch(
                  bankrollTotalProvider(bankroll.id),
                ).toString(),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                context.pushNamed(
                  AppRoute.gameSessionList.name,
                  pathParameters: {
                    'id': bankroll.id,
                    'bankrollName': bankroll.name!
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
        ],
      ),
      // ... [Consider handling other cases for the AsyncValue]
    );
  }
}
```

Here's how I calculate the `bankrollTotal`:

```dart
@riverpod
Future<double> bankrollTotal(
  BankrollTotalRef ref,
  String bankrollId,
) async {
  final gameSessionList = await ref
      .watch(gameSessionRepositoryProvider)
      .getGameSessionListForBankroll(bankrollId);

  final depositList = await ref
      .watch(depositRepositoryProvider)
      .getDepositListForBankroll(bankrollId);

  final gameSessionTotal = gameSessionList.fold(
      0.0, (sum, session) => sum + (session.cashout ?? 0.0));

  final depositTotal =
      depositList.fold(0.0, (sum, deposit) => sum + (deposit.amount));

  final totalBankroll = gameSessionTotal + depositTotal;
  return totalBankroll;
}
```

The problem I'm facing is when `bankrollTotalProvider` changes, it doesn't invoke the `build` method of the `BankrollListScreen` as it’s only being watched by `bankrollListControllerProvider`.

How can I make my `BankrollListScreen` rebuild when there are any changes in `bankrollTotalProvider`?

---

### Possible solution?

(It's not. I found answer see the second solution)

I believe I've found a solution.

The `ref.watch` will invoke the `build` method when the state of a provider changes. The issue with my code is that the state of `bankrollTotalProvider` doesn't alter unless I intervene manually.

Therefore, in this scenario, instead of monitoring the provider, we should create another widget that triggers the method manually.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:today_poker/features/statistics/service/bankroll_stat_service.dart';

class BankrollTotalTextWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  final String bankrollId;

  const BankrollTotalTextWidget({super.key, required this.bankrollId});

  Future<String> fetchBankrollTotal(WidgetRef ref) async {
    final value = await ref
        .watch(bankrollStatServiceProvider(bankrollId).notifier)
        .getBankrollTotal(bankrollId);
    return value.toString();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    Future<String> bankrollTotalFuture = fetchBankrollTotal(ref);
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: bankrollTotalFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data!);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print(snapshot.error);
            return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}");
          }
        }
        // While data is loading:
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then, I pass `BankrollTotalTextWidget` to `bankrollTotal`.

```dart
bankrollTotal: BankrollTotalTextWidget(bankroll.id),
```

### Solution

It's simple.
I inserted a logic to remove existing provider when I add a new value to the list.

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  // Get bankroll that I want to add this game session
  final bankroll = await ref.read(bankrollRepositoryProvider).getBankroll(id);

  // Add game session to the bankroll
  ref.watch(addGameSessionControllerProvider.notifier).addGameSession(bankroll);

  // Remove all cached data(provider)
  ref.invalidate(bankrollRepositoryProvider);
  ref.invalidate(gameSessionRepositoryProvider);
  ref.invalidate(depositRepositoryProvider);

  // Go to home
  if (context.mounted) {
    context.goNamed(AppRoute.home.name);
  }
},
```

That's the solution that finally worked for me. Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `ref.watch()` does not invoke `build()`, you can manually activate `ref.watch()` by calling `ref.invalidate()`. It removes existing providers.

##### Solution

It's simple: I inserted a logic to remove existing provider when I add a new value to the list.

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  // Get bankroll that I want to add this game session
  final bankroll = await ref.read(bankrollRepositoryProvider).getBankroll(id);

  // Add game session to the bankroll
  ref.watch(addGameSessionControllerProvider.notifier).addGameSession(bankroll);

  // Remove all cached data(provider)
  ref.invalidate(bankrollRepositoryProvider);
  ref.invalidate(gameSessionRepositoryProvider);
  ref.invalidate(depositRepositoryProvider);

  // Go to home
  if (context.mounted) {
    context.goNamed(AppRoute.home.name);
  }
},
```

That's the solution that finally worked for me. Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First, by reading your business logic (to which I'm basically unaware of) it's weird to see that `bankrollListControllerProvider` and `bankrollTotalProvider` are unrelated. I would expected a reactive dependency, such that `bankrollTotalProvider` *watches* `bankrollListControllerProvider` to compute its thing. But I see that's not the case.

Anyways...

> The problem I'm facing is when `bankrollTotalProvider` changes, it doesn't invoke the build method of the `BankrollListScreen` as it’s only being watched by `bankrollListControllerProvider`.

Something's wrong here. I'd suggest giving your list elements a `key` (e.g. based on `bankroll.id`) so that you can better debug why and how those elements are replaced by the framework.

You've correctly registered `bankrollTotalProvider(id)` as a dependency for `BankrollListScreen`, therefore this should definitely work.

#### A note on your "possible solution"

Have you tried to just use `final total = ref.watch(bankrollTotalProvider(id))` in that `BankrollTotalTextWidget`, instead? It basically does the same thing, except you won't use a `FutureProvider`, but the usual `AsyncValue` instead.

If that works, it means you've encountered a classic Flutter-ish "builder" problem. See [the docs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXNOkIuSYuA).

Comment: Sadly, `final total = ref.watch(bankrollTotalProvider(id));` in the `BankrollTotalTextWidget` didn't work.

Comment: I suspect it's related to the `gameSessionList` and `depositList` inside `bankrollTotalProvider`.

Comment: Fetching data from `bankrollTotalProvider` is not an issue. However, when I add a new element to `gameSessionList`, it doesn't automatically refetch new `gameSessionList`. So I updated it manually. –

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be updating the state of your `bankrollListControllerProvider` provider incorrectly. Try using `List.of` on update, or use the spread operator like this:

```
newState = ...;

state = List.of(newState);
// or

state = [...newState];
```

This will indicate to your `bankrollListControllerProvider` that its state has indeed been updated. All collections should use this state update approach. With simple types, you can do a simple assignment `state = newState;`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I will check that too!